# Combine multiple columns but keep only the highest value in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame. I want to merge the edu0, edu1, edu2, edu3 columns and create new column but only keeping the highest value per participant (id) in the column. In the new edu column NAs can be included. the order of the id or participants must not be changed. how do I do that?

example data below.

```
df <- data.frame(id = 11:60, edu0=1:50, edu1=rnorm(50), edu2=rpois(50, 10), edu3= 0:49)

library(naniar)

df <- df %>%
  replace_with_na(replace = list(edu0 = c(5,11),
                                 edu1 = c(1.1357996, -0.2710641), 
                                 edu2 = c(8, 12, 14, 15), 
                                 edu3= c(3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 15)))
```

Comment: Can you show your desired output based on the data you provided?

Comment: I want a new column with the maximum values of each rows of the edu0-edu3 columns. new column would have the following data: 13, 2 , 3, 7 etc.

Comment: Feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) any of the given answers. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(edu = max(edu0, edu1, edu2, edu3, na.rm=TRUE))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 50 x 6
# Groups:   id [50]
      id  edu0   edu1  edu2  edu3   edu
   <int> <int>  <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1    11     1 -1.36     NA     0     1
 2    12     2 -1.03      9     1     9
 3    13     3  0.660    11     2    11
 4    14     4 -0.527    13    NA    13
 5    15    NA  0.115     6     4     6
 6    16     6  1.83     13    NA    13
 7    17     7  2.03     10    NA    10
 8    18     8 -0.366    10    NA    10
 9    19     9  0.834    11     8    11
10    20    10 -0.483    16    NA    16
# ... with 40 more rows
```

#### NA Handling

Using

```r
df %>%
  rowwise %>% # in this case: alternative to group_by
  mutate(edu = ifelse(all(is.na(c(edu0, edu1, edu2, edu3))), # check if everything is NA
                      NA, 
                      max(edu0, edu1, edu2, edu3, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

handles rows with all `NA`'s.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to make a column with the maximum value from each row? If so just use a simple apply function.

```
df$maximum <- apply(X = df[,2:5],                     #data.frame without your id column
                MARGIN = 1,                           #apply this function over rows
                FUN = function(x) max(x,na.rm = TRUE) #maximum function with NA removed.
                )
```

Comment: thank you very much. But if I wanted to use the column names instead of column numbers how do I do it? do I use the " "?

Answer (score 1):

you can try a `dplyr_1.0.0` solution

```
df <- dplyr::mutate(df, edu_max = pmax(edu0, edu1, edu2, edu3, na.rm = T))
head(df)
id edu0         edu1 edu2 edu3 edu_max
1 11    1  0.004930678   13    0      13
2 12    2  1.010680957   12    1      12
3 13    3 -1.175384413   11    2      11
4 14    4 -0.782571202   10    3      10
5 15    5  0.896629873    9    4       9
6 16    6  1.234215881   13    5      13
```

Or use `across` to specify start and end column name:

```
dplyr::mutate(df, pmax(dplyr::across(edu0:edu3), na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option is using `pmax` in `do.call`

```
df$edu <- do.call(pmax,c(df[-1],na.rm = TRUE))
```